# jQuery validation for confirming password not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I was looking at the following question: [Password confirmation trouble with jQuery validation plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11070105/password-confirmation-trouble-with-jquery-validation-plugin)

I copied the code on jsfiddle and edited it accordingly to make it run on my server, but it doesn't seem to be working and I can't figure it out! Kindly help, thanks!

Here's my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>        
<script>
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    }
});

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        pass: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        pass2: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#pass"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        pass: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        pass2: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
            equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
        }
    }
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>
            <label for="pass"></label>
            <input id="pass" name="pass" type="password" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Password confirm</td>
        <td>
            <label for="pass2"></label>
            <input id="pass2" name="pass2" type="password" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you have the jQuery validate plugin script loaded? (because validator is a separate .js file)

Comment: Are you referring to this, <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

Comment: _"it doesn't seem to be working"_ - What _does_ it seem to be doing? What is the desired behaviour and what is the actual behaviour? Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Hi, I'm expecting it to show the error messages when the passwords don't match but it doesn't do that.

Comment: Maybe someone can try running the above code in their browser? =)

Comment: @Belgarion, made a fiddle with your code, works good, or? http://jsfiddle.net/VxUpC/

Comment: Try adding this around your code `$(document).ready(function() {` code here `});`

Comment: Thanks Sergio, looks like that's the problem, needed to wrap the js,

Comment: [tag:jquery-validation-engine] is a totally different plugin than yours.  Please be more careful when tagging. Edited.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping your JS this function

```
$(function () {
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() {
        alert("submitted!");
    }
});

// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        pass: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        pass2: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#pass"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        pass: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },
        pass2: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long",
            equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
        }
    }
});
 });
```

Comment: Great! When you look at the JSFiddle remember to see how the javascript is being loaded on the left side. If it says onLoad $(window).load(function(){ code here}); or domReady $(function(){ code here }); you will need to place it in those functions.

Comment: @dz15, Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086843/how-can-i-make-two-message-in-password-confirmation-in-jquery-validate. The case is same. But my case not required for password and password confirmation